# Problem : ant unable to recognize for task

Tags: ant

I am trying to iterate over all the files in a ant however ant seems to be unable to recognize for task.

I have installed ant-contrib on a location and have provided the path in the build file.

```
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}\build\ant-contrib.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>  
    <for param="file">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/objects"/>
        </path>
        <sequential>
            perform operations here.
        </sequential>
    </for>          
</target>   

Problem: failed to create task or type for
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest avoiding the use of ant-contrib if at all possible. If you have anything resembling a normal build, native Ant can probably handle it better. Feel free to post a higher level description what you're trying to do here and I can help you out with it.

That said, your task isn't recognized because `antcontrib.properties` doesn't define it, for some strange reason. Instead, try pointing the `resource` attribute to `antlib.xml`.

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${basedir}\build\ant-contrib.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```